# duplication avoidance when writing to picturebox and printer

Tags: printing, vb6, picturebox

So occasionally program in VB6 but I never solved this problem.

I have a Private Sub to draw lots of stuff to a picturebox like lines, text, pictures. Lots and lots of lines of code. But then i want to use same lines to draw to a printer object. But I don't know how to do it.

For example:

```
private sub command1_click()
    picture1.print "hello there"
    etc etc etc
end sub
private sub command2_click()
    printer.print "hello world"
    etc etc etc
    printer.print
end sub
```

to be

```
public sub pictureengine(action....)
    if action = draw then picturebox is selected for output
    if action = print then printer object is selected output 
    <object/control>.print "hello world"
    etc etc etc
    if action = print then printer.enddoc printer.print
end sub
```

There should be an alias to use controls/objects.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was faced with this exact issue.  I decided to abstract away the details of the PictureBox, Printer, or any other surface by implementing `Interfaces`.  You will end up with 3 classes:

- ISurface
- CPrinterSurface
- CPictureBoxSurface

**The ISurface Class** defines the interface and contains no code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Create(ByRef SurfaceObject As Object)
End Sub

Public Sub AddLine(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                   ByVal StartY As Double, _
                   ByVal EndX As Double, _
                   ByVal EndY As Double, _
                   Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = vbWhite, _
                   Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                   Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = vbSolid)
End Sub

Public Sub AddCircle(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                     ByVal StartY As Double, _
                     ByVal Radius As Double, _
                     Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = vbWhite, _
                     Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                     Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = vbSolid)
End Sub
```

**The CPrinterSurface Class** implements the interface.  This is where you add code.

```
Option Explicit

Implements ISurface

Private oPrinter As Printer

Private Sub ISurface_Create(SurfaceObject As Object)
   Set oPrinter = SurfaceObject
End Sub

Private Sub ISurface_AddLine(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                             ByVal StartY As Double, _
                             ByVal EndX As Double, _
                             ByVal EndY As Double, _
                             Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = 16777215, _
                             Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                             Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = 0&)
   oPrinter.DrawWidth = PenSize
   oPrinter.DrawStyle = PenStyle
   oPrinter.ForeColor = PenColor       
   oPrinter.Line (StartX, StartY)-(EndX, EndY), PenColor
End Sub

Private Sub ISurface_AddCircle(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                               ByVal StartY As Double, _
                               ByVal Radius As Double, _
                               Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = 16777215, _
                               Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                               Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = 0&)
   oPrinter.DrawWidth = PenSize
   oPrinter.DrawStyle = PenStyle
   oPrinter.ForeColor = PenColor
   oPrinter.Circle (StartX, StartY), Radius, PenColor
End Sub
```

**The CPictureBoxSurface Class** also implements the interface.

```
Option Explicit

Implements ISurface

Private oPictureBox As PictureBox

Private Sub ISurface_Create(SurfaceObject As Object)
   Set oPictureBox = SurfaceObject
End Sub

Private Sub ISurface_AddLine(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                             ByVal StartY As Double, _
                             ByVal EndX As Double, _
                             ByVal EndY As Double, _
                             Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = 16777215, _
                             Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                             Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = 0&)
   oPictureBox.DrawWidth = PenSize
   oPictureBox.DrawStyle = PenStyle
   oPictureBox.ForeColor = PenColor       
   oPictureBox.Line (StartX, StartY)-(EndX, EndY), PenColor
End Sub

Private Sub ISurface_AddCircle(ByVal StartX As Double, _
                               ByVal StartY As Double, _
                               ByVal Radius As Double, _
                               Optional ByVal PenColor As Long = 16777215, _
                               Optional ByVal PenSize As Integer = 1, _
                               Optional ByVal PenStyle As DrawStyleConstants = 0&)
   oPictureBox.DrawWidth = PenSize
   oPictureBox.DrawStyle = PenStyle
   oPictureBox.ForeColor = PenColor
   oPictureBox.Circle (StartX, StartY), Radius, PenColor
End Sub
```

**The Main App.** Create an EXE project containing the logic to generically produce your drawing.  Swap out the surface, and one codebase can draw to any implemented surface.  Your project tree will consist of the main form with a PictureBox and a Button, and the 3 classes described above.  Here is the code for the main form:

```
Option Explicit

Private MySurface As ISurface

Private Sub cmdCreate_Click()
   Set MySurface = New CPictureBoxSurface
   MySurface.Create Picture1
   MySurface.AddCircle 1000, 1000, 500, vbRed
   MySurface.AddCircle 1500, 1500, 500, vbBlue
End Sub
```

The code presented above eliminates duplication when you have multiple surfaces.  It has been stripped down for clarity and to highlight the basic architecture.  Hopefully you will be able to expound upon these concepts for your application.

Comment: I will give it a try in a new project and see how it works. So can i add more functions? I'm trying to make a program to render calendars in 2 sizes and some types. I basically use image for logo, text for the year, months, days, lines.for outlines. So far the program works but i am still killing bugs and make improvements. I want to avoid to print what's in the picturebox because the result sucks and printing text directly make text selectable if printed to a pdf printer.

Comment: Yes, certainly.  You can add as many functions as you like.  Just follow the pattern I presented.  My full app has a dozen or more functions, including AddText, AddPicture, AddRectangle, etc.  You can even implement other surfaces, such as PDF, AutoCAD, or XML.  This question is almost exactly what I went through a number of years ago and has worked out very well for me.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I finally tried today to use your code and vb6 refuses to run it, it complains about Implements keyword. Don't you have a project readly typed i can download?

Comment: @HugoSimões I simplified my original post a little bit, and then tried running it.  It runs fine.  What is the exact message you receive?

Comment: I took a screenshot: https://i.postimg.cc/6qRt91kd/vberror.png   , i repasted it as of above and i get that error

Comment: @HugoSimões You don't have a class called ISurface. You have a class called Class1 saved to a file named ISurface. Rename all 3 classes and you should be good to go.

Comment: *facepalm* You are completely and entirely right... It works now. I wished i had this solution years ago. Will play with it and see where I can go with it. Happy New Year for you!

Comment: @HugoSimões Glad to be of assistance, and Happy New Year to you, too! If this answer has been of assistance please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.